# Installing programs to another hard drive

Tags: software-installation

My C drive is only about 200 gigabytes since it's ssd, my D drive is 2 teras, how do i install programs into D drive, I am a total noob with ubuntu, thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to include current-window-only screenshots of `gparted` view of /dev/sda and /dev/sdb, then I can make a better recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the things you can install programs there but you will not be able to run them because the system will not recognize where the file is stored

Comment: How is this helpful? How does it answer the question?

Comment: I am trying to say unless you want to throw away a few days doing this you probably don't want to do this

Comment: That's not clear from your answer. Maybe if you edited your answer, and were more complete with your thought, we'd understand better. It needs to **answer the question** though.